# MeteorJS - No user system, how to filter data at the client end?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

The title might sound strange, but I have a website that will query some data in a Mongo collection. However, there is no user system (no logins, etc). Everyone is an anonymouse user.

The issue is that I need to query some data on the Mongo collection based on the input text boxes the user gives. Hence I cannot use this.userId to insert a row of specifications, and the server end reads this specifications, and sends the data to the client.

Hence:

```
// Code ran at the server
if (Meteor.isServer)
{
    Meteor.publish("comments", function ()
    {
        return comments.find();
    });
}

// Code ran at the client
if (Meteor.isClient)
{
    Template.body.helpers
    (
        {
            comments: function ()
            {
                return comments.find()
                // Add code to try to parse out the data that we don't want here
            }
        }
    );
}
```

It seems possible that at the user end I filter some data based on some user input. However, it seems that if I use `return comments.find()` the server will be sending a lot of data to the client, then the client would take the job of cleaning the data.

By a lot of data, there shouldn't be much (10,000 rows), but let's assume that there are a million rows, what should I do?

I'm very new to MeteorJS, just completed the tutorial, any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to read the docs, in particular [the section on Publish and Subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publishandsubscribe).

By changing the signature of your publish function above to one that takes an argument, you can filter the collection on the server, and limiting the data transferred to what is required.

```
Meteor.publish("comments", function (postId)
{
    return comments.find({post_id: postId});
});
```

Then on the client you will need a subscribe call that passes a value for the argument.

```
Meteor.subscribe("comments", postId)
```

Ensure you have removed the [autopublish](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/autopublish) package, or it will ignore this filtering.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this asap